# Having trouble understanding C code build warnings. Function definition is somehow wrong

Tags: c

I am trying to understand arrays/ pointers/ function and how to properly apply them in my beginning programming of C code.

This program shows a bunch of letters with a hidden word in it for a few seconds depending on the difficulty selected. It then gives you an opportunity to see if you found the hidden word. It does this three times then the game ends.

Code Blocks Compiler build warnings received:
(I have included line numbers in the code (at the end of the line) so it is easy to find what line the warning is pointing to)

```
80 Warning: passing argument 3 of 'verifyanswer' makes pointer from integer without a cast

10 note: expected 'int* ' but argument is of type 'int' In function 'verifyanswer':

114 warning: comparison between pointer and integer
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h> 
#include <string.h>
 #include <ctype.h>

void verifyanswer (char*StrGameArray, char response [], int Strlength []);// 10 10 10 10 10

int main () { 
char *StringGameArray [50] = {"cathoropordscodiscopwnsestropthprds",//disco                "cassormocedimahonahteidbballoonhelspq",//balloon "cheeszpistsrwhystacifitercinotonomwerd",};//why

int Stringlength [3] = {5,7,3};

char Response [80]={0};

int LevelChoice = 0; int DisplayTime = 0; int StartTime = 0; int Displayed = 0; int x = 0; system("clr");

while (LevelChoice !=4 )
{
  printf("\nWELCOME TO THE FIND THE WORD GAME!");
  printf("\nChoose your difficulty level 1-3");
  printf("\n\n 1-Super easy");
  printf("\n 2-Regular");
  printf("\n 3-Hard");
  printf("\n 4-Quit\n");
  scanf("%d",&LevelChoice);

     switch (LevelChoice)
    {
      case 1:
      DisplayTime = 5;
      break;

      case 2:
      DisplayTime = 3;
      break;

      case 3:
      DisplayTime = 1;
      break;


     }//end of switch


StartTime = time(NULL);

  for (x=0; x<3;x++)
     {
       //DISPLAY TEXT FOR A FEW SECONDS DICTATED BY DIFFICULTY CHOICE
       while (StartTime + DisplayTime > time(NULL))
          {
               if (Displayed == 0)
               {
                printf("\nFind a word in :\n\n");
                printf("%s\n\n",StringGameArray [x]);
                Displayed = 1;
               }//end if

          }//end while

       system("clear");

       printf("\nEnter found word\n");
       scanf("%s",Response);

       verifyanswer(StringGameArray[x],Response,Stringlength [x]);//function call  80 80 80 

       Displayed = 0;
       StartTime = time(NULL);


     }//end for loop 3x



}//end of while
return 0;
}//end of function main

void verifyanswer (char*StrGameArray, char response [],int Strlength []) {

int LenghtofResponse = 0;
LenghtofResponse = (strlen(response));

printf("\nResponse is %s",response);

//CONVERT ANSWER TO LOWER CASE TO PERFORM A VALID COMPARISON int x =0; for (x=0; x<= strlen(response);x++){ response[x] = (tolower (response[x]));}

if ( (strstr(StrGameArray,response) != 0)&&  (LenghtofResponse == Strlength) && (response[0] != 0)) //114 114 114 114 114 

printf("\nCongratulations you found the word");

else printf("\nYou did not find the word");

}//end of check answer
```

Comment: `"expected 'int* ' but argument is of type 'int' In function 'verifyanswer'..."` is pretty self-explanatory. Compilers have gotten very good at telling you exactly what the problem is. Slowing down and reading the warning/error closely will almost always tell you what needs attention.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared, and later defined, the function to take a `int[]`

```c
void verifyanswer (char*StrGameArray, char response [], int Strlength []);
```

That is already suspicious, because you would expect "length" to be an integer. And indeed, when you later call in in `main()`, you pass it an `int`

```c
int Stringlength [3] = {5,7,3};
//...
verifyanswer(StringGameArray[x],Response,Stringlength [x]);
```

That is what the warning means. The argument would be converted to a pointer to an int, but that is probably not what you intended.To fix it you should be declaring, and defining, the function to take an int:

```
void verifyanswer (char*StrGameArray, char response [], int Strlength);
```

Comment: How would you fix this warning?

Comment: By changing the function to `void verifyanswer (char*StrGameArray, char response [], int Strlength)`

Answer (score 0):

here

```
 verifyanswer(StringGameArray[x],Response,Stringlength [x]);/
```

you are passing a single int (`Stringlength [x]`)to `verifyanswer`. the function expects an array

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
void verifyanswer (char*StrGameArray, char response [],int Strlength [])
```

to:

```
void verifyanswer (char*StrGameArray, char response [],int Strlength)
```

Comment: This doesn't really add anything to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75654724/10871073), which also includes an explanation for the change.